# How do I join data on ICollection navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Based on the following model, I'm trying to include a number of navigation properties:

```
Assessment
\_ Sections
   \_ Questions
      \_ QuestionOptions
```

I'm using ICollection to group the child collections to their parent items:

```
public class Assessment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public Package Package { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AssessmentSection> Sections { get; set; }
}
public class AssessmentSection
{
    // Redacted properties for brevity.

    public ICollection<AssessmentQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}
public class AssessmentQuestion
{
    // Redacted properties for brevity.

    // Include AssessmentQuestionOptions for multiple choice questions.
    public ICollection<AssessmentQuestionOption> Options { get; set; }
}
public class AssessmentQuestionOption
{
    // Redacted properties for brevity.
}
```

What I'm finding right now is I need to `.Include()` the collections in my query to get the data coming through in my query:

```
var assessment = await context.Assessments.Include(x => x.Sections).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

This presents a problem because I don't seem able to `.Include()` the Questions and QuestionOption items.

How can I include every level of this structure in my query?

Comment: `Include` doesn't JOIN. It tells EF Core to eagerly load related Sections. Without it, EF Core would load each Section instance when the property was accessed. Same with Question and QuestionOption. If you really want to eagerly load all related entities use`.ThenInclude()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `.ThenInclude()` for subentities.

[See the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-entityframeworkqueryableextensions-theninclude-3(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-query-iincludablequeryable((-0-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))))-system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-1-2))))))

Also see the main data about eager loading EF core related entities:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#including-multiple-levels